# Mongo behaviour once master is down?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Consider the below diagram in MongoDB

[image]

I have two scenarios

**Scenario 1 :-**

Router directs the write call to master.Its writen to master but then it goes down before it gets replicted to slaves(i am using 
synch replication mode)
Will router select one slave as master and also write the above request to both slaves ?

**Scenario 2 :-**
Router directs the write call to master. Its writen to master but then  network link b/w it and one slave is broken(using 
synch replication mode)
Will router select another slave(which is connected to all other nodes) as master and also write the above request to  slave  ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's first use MongoDB terminologies: [Primary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-primary/) instead of master and [Secondary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-secondary/) instead of slave.

> Scenario 1: Will router select one slave as master and also write the above request to both slaves ?

A secondary can become a primary. If the current primary becomes unavailable, the replica set holds an election to choose which of the secondaries becomes the new primary. See also [Replica Set Elections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/#replica-set-elections).

In scenario 1, if the primary had accepted write operations that the secondaries had not successfully replicated before the primary stepped down, then a rollback will revert the write operations on a former primary when the node rejoins the replica set. See also [RollBacks During Replica Set Failover](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/).

You can run all voting members with journaling enabled and use [writeConcern majority](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/#wc-w) to prevent rollbacks. See also [Avoid Replica Set Rollbacks](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/#avoid-replica-set-rollbacks).

> Scenario 2: Will router select another slave(which is connected to all other nodes) as master and also write the above request to slave ?

There are two parts here, the first part is replica set election. In this case because the primary and one of the secondaries are still majority, no election will be held. The primary will still be primary and replicating to one of the secondaries.

The second part is about replication of data. Secondary members copy [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) from their `sync source` and apply these operations in an asynchronous process. A secondary `sync source` may automatically change as needed based on changes in the ping time and state of other members’ replication. See also [Replica Set Data Synchronization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-sync/#replica-set-data-synchronization)

In scenario 2, the secondary may change its sync source to the other secondary.

You may also found the following useful:

- [Replica Set High Availability](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-high-availability/)
- [Replica Set Deployment Architectures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/)
- [Replica Set Distributed Across Two or More Data Centers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architecture-geographically-distributed/)